# button ouside d3.js svg to select and modify d3.js elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have svg graph generated via d3.js, and click events attached to DOM generated by d3.js works, but a precreated DOM outside d3.js simply does not fire the event

```
//d3.js generated DOM
var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
                .data(data)
                .each(transform) // update existing markers
                .enter().append("svg")
                .each(transform)
                .attr("class", function (d) {
                    return d[12] === "Region" ? "marker region" : "marker";
                });

//pre-created DOM
var btn = d3.select('#vslCur_btn0');

//method i'd like to trigger on click
var hideAct = function(){
                console.log("trying to hide"+marker.size());
                marker.filter(function (d) {
                    return d[12] === "Region";
                }).style("width", function (d) {
                    console.log('attr lulz:' + d3.select(this).style('width'));
                    return d3.select(this).style('width') === '70px' ? '0px' : '70px';
                });                
        };  

marker.on("click", hideAct);//works when clicked displays "trying to hide295" or the number of svg
btn.on("click", hideAct);//does not work but displays "trying to hide0" on console
```

Obviously `#vslCur_btn0` exists outside the svg. In case `selectAll("svg")` bothers you there are multiple absolute position svgs within a div which serves as some sort of canvas (google maps), `#vslCur_btn0` exists outside of that canvas and is some sort of control panel. the questions is

1. Why d3js treats `#vslCur_btn0` as outside scope
2. How to override this scope problem and make it work on 'outsider' DOM

Comment: That's incorrect, buttons outside the SVG work just fine. Please, paste your dot_click function.

Comment: sorry that was typo, original code was much longer, this is concise version

Comment: edited the code again, added size checking, noticed that marker.size() will display 0 on outsider DOM while it displays 295 on d3js insider DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> click events attached to DOM generated by d3.js work, but a precreated DOM outside d3.js simply does not fire the event.

This is wrong, it does fire. The problem here seems to be the use of `this`.

In your `hideAct` function, you are using `this` to change the style of a given svg element. The problem is, when you click the button, `this` is the button itself, not the SVG element.

Here is a fiddle demo, that calls a function on click to log the radius of the circle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/42yLuhfb/

I'm using the same pattern in your code:

```
circles.on("click", test);//clicking on the SVG element
d3.select("#btn").on("click", test);//clicking on the HTML button
```

Click the circle first, and after that click the button, comparing the results. Pay attention to the console, it logs `this` and the `r`. For the button, the `r` result is, of course, `null`

**PS**: I'd rather use SO snippet instead of an external link (JSfiddle), but unfortunately SO snippet is freezing when we try to console.log `this`.